# Modular quadratic equation (solve for 3-digit natural numbers)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratics

*$n^2 + 6n - 88$ is divisible by 97. Solve for all n if n is a 3-digit natural number.*

Here's my progress so far

$$n^2 + 6n - 88 \equiv 0\pmod {97}$$
$$n^2 + 6n - 88 + 97 \equiv 0\pmod {97}$$
$$n^2 + 6n + 9 \equiv 0\pmod {97}$$
$$(n+3)^2 \equiv 0\pmod {97}$$

I know $97$ is prime, but can't figure out how to use this fact. I can't just take the sqrt, can I?

Any hints, tips or anything else highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Your last step implies that (n+3) is divisible by 97 (since if a<sup>2</sup> is divisible by b, a should also be divisible by b. Just list all three digit factors of 97, and subtract 3 from each to get to the answer. So your answer is 191, 288, 385, 482, 579, 676, 773, 870, 967.